# Wildfly : application deployed but not running

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss, wildfly, ear

I'm trying to deploy an .ear application to Wildfly 10.1 final. The .ear has 2 nested .war files. There's no "jboss-web.xml" file in the .war files.

Here's the application.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
    <display-name>myApp-ear</display-name>
    <description>myApp</description>
    <module>
      <web>
        <web-uri>myApp-rest</web-uri>
        <context-root>/myApp-rest</context-root>
      </web>
    </module>
    <module>
      <web>
        <web-uri>myApp-webapp</web-uri>
        <context-root>/myApp-webapp</context-root>
      </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

After deploying, I have the following log :

> INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found myApp.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called myApp.ear.dodeploy 
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myApp.ear" (runtime-name: "myApp.ear") 
>   WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar in /C:/Dev/Wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/myApp.ear/liquibase-core-3.3.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. 
>   (...) 
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "myApp-rest") 
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "myApp-webapp") 
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "myApp.ear" (runtime-name : "myApp.ear")

And that's all, no "register" in the logs or something like that.
So, whenever I try to access "localhost:8080/myApp-webapp" I have a 404 error.

The application was previously deployed on Weblogic 11 (with the same configuration) and it worked fine.

Any clue ?

Comment: Did you create a file called `myApp.ear.dodeploy`?

Comment: Actually yes, each time I create this file in the deployement folder, myApp gets deployed again with the following message : 
"WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "myApp.ear" with deployment "myApp.ear"".
But the problem remains.

Comment: Is this an exploded deployment? If so you'll want to have an extension on your `myApp-rest` and `myApp-webapp`, i.e. `myApp-rest.jar` `myApp-webapp.war`.

Comment: I have already tried to add an extension (first thing that crossed my mind), but that changes nothing

Comment: Is this an exploded deployment?

Comment: In the "deployment" folder, the 2 .war files are unzipped, and a "myApp.ear.deployed" file is present. In the other hand, I don't know if this folder is relevant. In the standalone.xml file I don't have a "auto-deploy-exploded" property.

Comment: Does the directory structure look something like `myApp.ear/myApp-rest.war` and `myApp.ear/myApp-webapp.war`?

Comment: It looks more like "myApp.ear/myApp-res" and "myApp.ear/myApp-webapp" (the files have no extension). I've already tried to add ".war" and change the "application.xml" file to reflect this change.

Comment: The directories need the file extension for them to be seen as WAR files. They need to be named `myApp.ear/myApp-res.war` and `myApp.ear/myApp-webapp.war`.

Comment: You're right . After changing everything to have the extensions and after multiple tries, I now have a bunch of errors (the application.properties file can't be found) but they don't seem to be related to my original problem. You can post your answer and I'll check it, thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following log messages it looks like the contents of your EAR are missing the appropriate file extensions

```
INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "myApp-rest") 
INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "myApp-webapp") 
INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "myApp.ear" (runtime-name : "myApp.ear")
```

Specifically note the `myApp-rest` and `myApp-webapp`. Those should both have a `.war` extension even if this is an exploded deployment. (Note the `myApp-rest` may have a `.jar` extension if it's just an EJB module.)