# Wildfly: web service deployed but unavailable

Tags: java, maven, soap, jboss, wildfly

## Problem description:

I want to deploy a web service through Wildfly and it gets deployed, but I cannot access it through a web browser.

This is what I do:

1. I run `standalone.sh`
2. I deploy the project using `mvn clean package wildfly:deploy`

Then I try to access my webservice through a web browser at `http://localhost:8080/lab-ear/Hello?wsdl` but I get only: "404 - Not Found"

Fragment of [maven logs](https://pastebin.com/TRya1zAE) while deploying. 

Here are [logs](https://pastebin.com/EG02Zzyt) from Wildfly server when it gets initialized.

And here [Wildfly logs](https://pastebin.com/ndQXaWan) during deploy.

## Other details:

I've done another project where the web service worked, but there were other problems, so I started everything from scratch.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPk2C.png) is the comparison of structures of these two projects. On the left the old project and on the right the new project.

**The important thing is that in the new project I don't get the `web` directory.**

Maybe related problem:

[Wildfly : application deployed but not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021503/wildfly-application-deployed-but-not-running)

**Also, is it required to use Intellij IDEA in such projects?**

### EDIT

In my EJB module I have a class [Hello](https://pastebin.com/k4tkDBcp) in package pl.edu.agh.soa

I tried to change from this:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class Hello {
...
```

to:

```
@Stateless(name = "Hello")
@WebService(name = "HelloService")
public class Hello {
...
```

But it also doesn't work.

Comment: It's unclear if this is a problem with your code because we're not seeing any.  Where is your JAX-WS code for the service?

Comment: @stdunbar I have added this code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I think I had unnecessarily changed too many dependencies' versions in `pom.xml` files.

Also, in main `pom.xml` file only `<version.wildfly.maven.plugin>` needed upgrading from `1.0.2.Final` to `2.0.2.Final`, but earlier I had also changed other plugins' versions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a simple "HelloWorld" type JAX-WS service running with just the code:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@Stateless
public class HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello( String name ) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

From this I'm able to access the URL `http://localhost:8080/<web-app-name>/HelloWorld?wsdl`.  This is in Wildfly 18.

The issue is that you don't specify a `@WebMethod`.  While the class is marked correctly there isn't anything to "run" in it.

Additionally, while it does work with the `@Stateless` EJB annotation that isn't required for JAX-WS but may be required for your code.

Comment: But I have already a @WebMethod annotation in my code. For example before the listSubjects() method.

Comment: @WojciechŁupina - that isn't clear from what you've posted so far.  However, in going back over you post I see you're deploying to `lab-web.war`.  Have you tried going to `http://localhost:8080/lab-web/Hello?wsdl`?

Comment: Actually, I tried to deploy to `lab-ear.ear` by running `mvn clean package wildfly:deploy` and after going to `http://localhost:8080/lab-ear/Hello?wsdl` I get the `404 - Not Found` error. But when I tried now to deploy to `lab-web.war` and go to `http://localhost:8080/lab-war/Hello?wsdl`,  I get a `Not Found` error (without `404`).

Comment: I'm sure that in my project the EAR file should be deployed, not WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA is not required at all.

I think your issue is the missing web directory. Without WEB-INF/web.xml the app server won't know what it is supposed to serve.

Comment: Modern web projects do not require a `web.xml` anymore.  It can all be pulled into annotations.

Comment: @stdunbar I thought it could be a problem with annotations, but I'm not sure.